# Error when trying to logout

Tags: errors

This problem was reported on the WP forum a month ago: [Error when trying to logout](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-when-trying-to-logout). Whenever you logout, you get (Chrome):

> **This webpage is not available.**
>
> The webpage at
>   http://my.site.com/blog/wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=2d5b319c49
>   might be temporarily down or it may
>   have moved permanently to a new web
>   address.
>
> More information on this error Below
>   is the original error message
>
> Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET):
>   Unknown error.

I've had this problem since at least 3.0.2 and it's still there with 3.0.4. My host is IPOWER.

I was wondering if anyone here has seen this problem, and even more importantly, has a solution.

Thanks.

A little more information:

1. I get the same connection reset
   error with FireFox and IE.
2. The Apache access log shows the following (I don't have access to the error logs):

   [22/Jan/2011:00:01:39 -0500] "GET /blog/wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=2d5b319c49 HTTP/1.0" **302** 212 "http://my.site.com/blog/wp-admin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.237 Safari/534.10"

The temporary redirect to /blog/wp-admin/ seems to make sense -- after logging out you go back to the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to WP 3.0.5 a couple of days ago and the problem persisted. I just updated to [Askimet 2.5.3](http://blog.akismet.com/2011/02/08/akismet-plugin-version-2-5-3-for-wordpress/), and voila!, the logout problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress itself is not resetting connections normally (at least I have not experienced it so far), so the connection gets shut down by one of those: a) the webserver, b) a http firewall, c) an IDS, d) a tcp/ip firewall or just by e) network hardware.

As you can reproduce the problem, you might want to contact IPOWER and while they real-time montior the network connection and server infrastructure you can trigger the error again. The networks and servers administrators should be able to find the real cause of your problem.

In case you request does not even reach the server, you might have some application running inside/alongside chrome / firefox that is forcing the connection to reset on the client side.

As far as you're concerned to fix it on your end, take a browser that is not having the problem.

An additional question: After getting that connection reset message, are you actually logged out from the blog or not? If not, this is a sign for the client/server problem. If yes, then probably Wordpress is triggering this. But I suspect some network problem in combination with HTTP headers send by those two browsers, but it's hard to say with the information you provided.

Comment: Not logged out. All of the WP forum reports were the same. What's surprising is that this is happening intermittently across a wide variety of hosts and browsers.

Comment: Okay, try to find out more with a proper network traffic analysis while reproducing the requests and some team on the hosting side. Do you see any chance to figure that out with your hoster support? Otherwise what you could do yourself is to check wether or not the login request reaches PHP by doing some debug output on the server side.